# For $1\leq x<2$, $\frac{n^{-x}}{n!}x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)$ is lower bounded

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, special-functions, gamma-function, limsup-and-liminf

I do not find the following statement obvious. The context is to show the gauss product representation of gamma function satisfying one of the characteristic properties of gamma function being bounded in $1\leq x<2$.

For large $n\in N,1\leq x<2$, $\frac{n^{-x}}{n!}x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)>a>0$ for some $a\geq 0$. This bound should be universal bound for large $n$.

I tried by $\frac{x}{1}\frac{x+1}{2}\cdots\frac{x+n-1}{n}\frac{n}{n^{x}}$. However $1\leq x<2$ does not grant me permission to conclude that this is non-zero.

Is this fact obvious?

Comment: "For large $n\in N,1\leq x<2\frac{n^{-x}}{n!}x(x+1)⋯(x+n)>a>0$." I don't understand this statement. Do you mean to have a comma somewhere?

Comment: @user474330 Corrected.